# Drop Table if Creation Date less than current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I trying to learn how I can drop a table based on the creation date.  If the creation date of the table is from today, keep the table, otherwise drop it and recreate it.

I am able to drop the table if exists, but I only want to drop the table if the table was created from an earlier date than today.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME 
= 'Search') DROP TABLE dbo.Search

(SELECT IssueID,IssueDate,D.Name As SectionName,C.Name As CategoryName,(B.FirstName + ' ' + B.LastName) As AssignedTo,Subject,Body,
Convert(date, getdate()) TableDate

INTO Search

FROM hdIssues A, hdUsers B, hdCategories C, hdSections D WHERE 
(A.AssignedToUserID = B.UserID AND A.CategoryID = C.CategoryID AND 
C.SectionID = D.SectionID))
```

Comment: Please tell us what software and environment you are using so someone with the appropriate experience can answer. At the moment there are not enough details.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad application design.  I don't think I have ever used the create date of a table for this purpose.

Comment: Which flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 R2. I believe I may try to figure out how to do a stored procedure that will drop this table then recreate it each night automatically.

and @GordonLinoff you're probably right about it "sounds like a really bad application design" Good job in daunting new persons in wanting to strive to be better by asking questions here!  Just and FYI, in the future why not offer whatever expertise you may have in best practices with helping someone instead of discouraging them, because how does someone know what they don't know?